# Bypassing the NSFW warning page using random-puppy and discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, reddit

I'm trying to make a meme bot (that uses reddit), but some of the subreddits have an NSFW warning page, which stops random-puppy from getting the images, how do i bypass that? I am welcome to getting alternates for random-puppy if you know about something better

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Sends a meme",
    async execute(message, args){
        const Discord = require("discord.js");
        const bot = new Discord.Client();
        const ms = require("ms");
        const moment = require("moment");
        const colors = require("colors");
        const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

        const memeSubreddits = ["dankmemes", "memes", "meme", "me_irl", "meirl", "comedyheaven", "NSFWMemes", "okbuddyretard"]
        const memeRandom = memeSubreddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * memeSubreddits.length)];

        const memeImage = await randomPuppy(memeRandom);
        const memeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setImage(memeImage)
            .setTitle(`From r/${memeRandom}`)
            .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${memeRandom}`);

        message.channel.send(memeEmbed); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [memejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memejs) for getting memes from Reddit. As its package name suggests, it gets memes but you can also filter what it gathers from.

As an example, you can do this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Sends a meme",
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message) {
        const {
            meme
        } = require('memejs');

        meme(function (err, data) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            const Discord = require('discord.js');
            const memeRes = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle(data.title)
                .setImage(data.url)
                .setFooter(data.subreddit)
                .setTimestamp('Created ' + data.created)
            message.channel.send(memeRes).then().catch(console.error);

        });

    },
}
```

As with every Node package you can play around with them on RunKit. You can do that [here](https://npm.runkit.com/memejs)

Also, as a little tip, you do not need to declare modules that are not being used in the command. This essentially gets rid of the following from your command:

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const ms = require("ms");
const moment = require("moment");
const colors = require("colors");
```

Comment: that last tip i did know, but it was just something i forgot to remove, nevertheless, thanks for the late answer

Comment: @oZion another note worth mentioning is that it does take around 5-7 seconds for the command to run, so keep that in mind.